# C# lambda syntax

Tags: c#, lambda

I have used lambda syntax before but I keep seeing the following kind of syntax, not sure how to interpret this, is there are more conventional way of writing these so I can compare the two and understand better.

This is one of the examples I have seen:

```
       client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response, asyncHandle) =>
        {
            Assert.NotNull(response.Content);
            Assert.Equal(val, response.Content);
            resetEvent.Set();
        });
```

This is another example:

```
        client.SearchAsync("Getting", s =>
                    {
                     Assert.IsNotNull(s);
                     Assert.AreEqual(1, s.Count);
                    }, 
                    Assert.IsNull);
```

Is there a way of writing these without lambda so I can understand them?

Thanks

Comment: It's called statement lambda. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Those lambdas are nearly identical, one just skipped the () around the parameters.

Comment: I have updated the question, the 2 statements are the ones I am trying to understand, they are from different code base.

Comment: That *is* the conventional way of writing that. There are more verbose methods of writing that, which may be more familiar to you, but it depends on what you're used to.

Comment: When you say writing these conventionally, do you mean without using a lamba?

Comment: @Sam Greenhalgh, yes, exactly, I am asking if we can write them without using lambda.

Comment: Then brz's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I thought the point of a lambda was to make it convenient. I feel so lied to.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET little of a joke OP states ` is there are more conventional way of writing these` meaning this is not convenient.

Comment: @CalvinSmith Gotcha. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, Lambdas are like methods. This is a roughly equivalent code:

```
private SomeMethod(List<string> s)
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(s);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, s.Count);
}

clientSearchAsync("Getting", SomeMethod, Assert.IsNull);
```

In a nutshell, you're passing SomeMethod to SearchAsync method as a parameter, and SearhAsync invokes it in its body.